# How to correctly perform a http request with Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope, ktor-client

So, I have a following function which does a basic request using Ktor client to get a list of users,

```
suspend fun createRequest(): List<User>? {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val client = HttpClient(CIO)
            val response: HttpResponse = client.get("http://10.0.2.2:9999/users")
            client.close()
            val str = response.readText()
            val itemType = object : TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.type
            Gson().fromJson<List<User>>(str, itemType)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I use this as following,

```
runBlocking {
    val res = async {createRequest()}
    val users = res.await()
    Log.v("_APP_", users.toString())
}
```

But then I read `runBlocking` should be used in testing and debugging and is not recommended for production. then what do I use instead of `runBlocking`?

Comment: You should be running your coroutine in a scope. Maybe you should take a look at a tutorial? The official one is sufficient: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using `runBlocking()` in a production. It just should not be overused by applying everywhere we need to run supendable code from outside of coroutines context. It is better to make outer function also suspendable and propagate further, but at some point you need to start a coroutine and `runBlocking()` is just for this.

Comment: Also, you need to understand that coroutines were designed to not block and make our code synchronous. Your `async()` and immediate `await()` does not make any sense, you can replace it with just: `val users = createRequest()` - it does the same thing. Similarly, I believe you don't need to (should not) wrap Ktor client with `Dispatchers.IO` as Ktor client was designed to work with coroutines and it doesn't block threads - it suspends.

Comment: @HenryTwist I did but this whole coroutines usage was a bit confusing to me. Anyway I will take a look at that article too. Thanks!

Comment: @broot Thanks a lot for the explanation. I think its a bit clear to me now

Comment: @broot I would say `runBlocking` on Android is *almost* always a code smell. You're typically working from the framework classes, so a coroutine scope is already provided. And when it's not, you can easily create a scope so you have better control over the concurrency. The only example I can think of is if you're working with a library that doesn't provide synchronous overloads to its asynchronous tasks and you need to run some function synchronously because you're managing some threads outside the coroutine system. And I've never encountered this hypothetical situation.

Comment: @Damon, since you're using the HttpClient locally only, you should use the `use` function to make the request and automatically close it. Otherwise, with your current code you could leak it because it won't reach the `close()` call if the get request throws.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ahh, ok, I didn't notice android tag, so I answered it as a generic Kotlin question. Yes, all Android components are managed by the framework, their lifecycle is precisely defined and most of them may be destroyed at any time, so it makes sense to stick to scopes tightly related to these components.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Aah that makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`createRequest()` is a `suspend` function and it must be called from a coroutine or another `suspend` function. There are a couple of coroutine builders:

- `runBlocking` - It is not recommended for production because it blocks the current thread.
- `launch` - launches a new coroutine concurrently with the rest of the code, which continues to work independently.
- `async` - creates a coroutine and returns its future result as an implementation of `Deferred`.

In Android there are a couple of ways to launch a coroutine, please refer to [these docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines).

To launch a coroutine you should have an instance of `CoroutineScope`, it can be `viewModelScope` (from the docs), `lifecycleScope` (from the docs) or custom instance. The sample code will look similar to:

```
scope.launch {
    val users = createRequest()
    Log.v("_APP_", users?.toString())
}
```